# Move elements to MODAL page Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm doing an application. It has a table with one row with some field. Then, the user can add rows and fill the new fields. In every rows I put one checkbox. With a button the user can print a barcode of checked input. I have two example: http://plnkr.co/edit/z2nXgXyGi6LhSHth8ZNi?p=preview and http://plnkr.co/edit/3DrWMSssx5UaQfHADoEr?p=preview (here you have to press Update to show the barcode).

The barcode iterate correctly. But my problem is that i want to show barcode of the checked rows in a new page (even modular window) because then the user can press a button to print. But i don't know how: 
-To keep all the barcode together, in a block outside the rows;
-To move the div of all barcode in a modular window.

I tried with jQuery to clone the image of barcode..but i think it is a bad practice to mix angular and jQuery: http://plnkr.co/edit/j7SLNZQwXfce2nCcCnbu?p=preview

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#clicca').on('click', function(e) {
$('#barcodeImage').each(function() {
var images = $('img[src^="data:image"]').clone();
$('#immagini').html(images);
});  });  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i'm getting the question correct but mixing jQuery with angular is [fine](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library-).
When you include jQuery in you site angular will detect it and you will be able to access it via the [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the
>   application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your
>   script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the
>   subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

So instead of $ you should use angular.element.

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."